# Received: [SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0]

Tags: javascript, jestjs, fetch, enzyme

I am trying to write test for a service that makes ajax call via fetch api. The service look like below.

```
export function authService(user, apiEndpoint) {
  return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/${apiEndpoint}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: user,
  })
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(json => {
    return json;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    return error;
  });
};
```

My tests look like this.

```
it('should success upon fetch request', async () => {
        await expect(authService()).resolves.toBe(JSON.stringify({
            success: true,
            message: 'Logged in successfully.',
        }));
    });
```

But it is showing my below error.

```
Expected: "{\"success\":true,\"message\":\"Logged in successfully.\"}"
    Received: [SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0]

      88 |
      89 |  it('should success upon fetch request', async () => {
    > 90 |      await expect(authService()).resolves.toBe(JSON.stringify({
         |                                           ^
      91 |          success: true,
      92 |          message: 'Logged in successfully.',
      93 |      }));
```

It seems like it is not returning a json object which I am expecting. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Shouldn't this `await expect(authService())` be `expect(await authService())`?

Comment: @Yousaf it doesn't fix that problem.

Comment: Your API is returning HTML, not JSON. It's probably some kind of error page from the server.

Comment: @Pointy the server returns json when I run the code.

Comment: Well apparently it doesn't, or you would not be getting that error: "position 0", doesn't that suggest that the response starts with something like `<!DOCTYPE` ??

Comment: You could of course add `console.log(response)` to your code.

Comment: You can try the same API call using Postman and see what it returns. Or just log it in the console.